# To Compare data between 2 excel sheets and copy data to the first sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, compare

I got excel data upto 58000 rows with 10 columns in two sheets to be compared.

Col A in both sheets has got few common names. if Sheet1, a10 = sheet2, a15, then i need to copy sheet2 b15, c16, etc to k10,l10 etc.

is there any way i can do it through vba?

thanks
solomon

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA.  Just use a VLOOKUP function.  You can use something like the following in K2 on Sheet1.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$J$58000,2,false),"")
```

And for L2:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$J$58000,3,false),"")
```

etc.

Comment: Sorry didnt work.  i need it to check if the value in Col A is equal to Value Col A Sheet 2 then copy the values from Sheet2 to Sheet 1 in the respective rows.